# COM library feasibility with Dynamics 365

Tags: com, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I'm searching to see if it's possible creating a payment connector similar to the one in this diagram:
[Connector Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM4cT.jpg)

I have a COM library which receives requests, communicates with the payment device & payment provider, and returns back their responses.

The COM library is registered locally:

```
COMLib /Register
```

I just pass user account & password to authenticate:

```
Authenticate(user, password)
```

I pass DeviceAddress & StoreCode to register payment device:

```
RegisterDevice(DeviceAddress, StoreCode);
```

Then pass amount, currency, (...) for transactions:

```
 CreateTransaction(merchantDetails,amount,currency,transactionType, merchantReference,orderReference,shopperEmail);
```

I don't need to deal with any endpoints as that's hidden and the COM library handles that.

Can this connector be created in Dynamics 365 ?

Any suggestions ?

Does anyone have code examples or useful links ?

I've checked D365 documentation and it looks that the Hardware Station is the nearest thing to what I need to achieve.

Thank you for your help.